# How do I structure a URL with several querystring items?

Tags: design, url

I have a URL like this `http://myserver/controller/action/var1/value/var2/value...`

Instead of `?var1=value...`

Is putting the variable name and value like that a good way to do this?  I'm using a ReWrite rule that will get my places in the URL at the moment, so I can parse it.

Comment: Doesn't look too great to me. Could become very confusing soon. Have a look at RESTful routing.

Comment: I thought it was RESTful.  I don't have the PUT, etc. in the string.

Comment: Is this asking the same thing? **[REST API Structure](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/245912/22815)**?

Comment: @Snowman It looks like it is.  The answer seems to be "whatever makes sense."

Comment: @johnny That is REST for you. The only rules are "it is URL-based and uses HTTP actions." Everything else is up to you.

Comment: It also addresses 'resources' which can be nested and structuring the variables into the URL like this could become a pain. Not necessarily, since most likely names of resources would be different from parameter/variable names. But still... Personally I would always prefer a 'cleaner' approach where the `path` part locates the resource and additional params that are key/value pairs go into the `query string`.

Comment: You mean with the question mark? instead of the slashes?

Comment: Yes, the stuff behind the question mark. That's where all the additional params go. Stuff that's not directly related to address the resource. But of course some details may depend on what framework to use. For example in Ruby on Rails your method would be a big pain and lots of additional work to setup the routes.

Comment: @thorstenmüller Does it matter if POST is used instead of GET?  Querystring makes me think of GET.

Comment: No, just the same. If you post a form from the browser that is where all the form fields data goes for example.